# How to remove title from category page in header

Tags: categories

I am trying to not show the page title on certain pages, including home, a custom post types page, and a category page (/category/blog). I came up with this, and it's working for everything  but the blog page.

```
if ( !is_front_page()  && !is_post_type_archive('location') && !is_page_template('category-blog.php')) :

<div class="page-title">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-3"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></div>
</div><!-- /row -->
</div><!-- /title -->

 endif;
```

Comment: Do you mean remove it from the <title> tag? or in the loop? The "category/blog" means there's a category with the name "blog"?

Comment: Not THE title, but a title I am adding to pages. I got it figured out finally.  !is_category( 'blog' ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do but most of the time to target blog page you will have to use :

```
if( is_home() || is_front_page() )
```

I know this could be a little bit confusing but [check this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home). `!is_home()` might be the condition you're looking for.